# JavaScript not Sending Parameter to Controller MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following view

```
@using System.Linq;
@model MyCompanyNET.Models.ViewModels.AdministratorViewModel

<style type="text/css">
    span {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    ...
</style>

<div class="manage">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#invite">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span>Invite
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="invite" class="tab-pane active fade in">
            @Html.Partial("_InvitePartial", Model)
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
                var data_email = $('#email').val();
                var data_product = $('#product option:selected').text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SendInvite")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { email: data_email, product: data_product },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#fail_message').html(result.result_failure);
                        $('#success_message').html(result.result_success);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

The partial view is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendInvite", "Tools", FormMethod.Post,
    new
    {
        @class = "form-horizontal",
        enctype = "multipart/form-data",
        role = "form"
    }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h2>Invite Users</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", id = "email" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Access To", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Product", new SelectList(
                new List<Object> {
                    new { Text = "Product1", Value = "Product1" },
                    new { Text = "Product2", Value = "Product2" },
                    new { Text = "All", Value = "All" }},
                    "Value",
                    "Text"),
                    new { @class = "form-control", id = "product" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <span id="fail_message" class="label label-danger"></span>
            <span id="success_message" class="label label-success"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" value="Invite User" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and my controller is

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<JsonResult> SendInvite(string email, string product)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    string result = String.Empty;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                result_success = String.Empty,
                result_failure = "Please enter and email address"
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    ... // Do stuff with email and product.
}
```

Now when this partial view code was in the view itself, everything worked fine. I'd get both the entered email address and the selected product coming through to my controller method `SendInvite`, but now the button does not even fire.

Now, I have changed the

```
<input type="button" value="Invite User" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

to use `submit`

```
<input type="submit" value="Invite User" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

This now calls my controller method but without the `email` parameter, which is always `null`(?). To make things worse, the `return Json(new ...` also does not render my `<span id="success_message" class="label label-success"></span>`s and it used to when everything was in the main view. Why is this occurring and how an I fix it?

Thank for your time.

Comment: Did you look at HTML / debug you JavaScript?

Comment: Dude, I am so noob I don't know how to debug the javascript. I have tried setting break points in VS2013, in the javascript but they never get hit. Any links or advice?

Comment: If you open the debug console in Chrome (not sure if others have it), go to network tab and submit the form. You should see a new request appear in the box, click it and look at the Form Data. I have the sneaking suspicion that it's passing the email under a different name than .NET is expecting. Either way, it will let you know if the problem is your view or your controller.

Comment: you need to debug javascript from the browser.  Once the view is rendered, MVC is done with it until you call another method.  That's the stateless nature of the web.

Comment: Telerik makes a tool every mvc developer should have call Fiddler.  Works with chrome and ie.   http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Generally F12 will open dev tools for browser. Than there would be script/sources tab to debug. You can also convince VS to debug script, but browser tools are generally better (and don't require VS installed on box with the browser). Frequently just looking at console in debug tools enough to know the issue.

Comment: Guys, thanks so so much for this help, it is most appreciated. I work for a small company and have been asked to develop a new site. It is going well but I have zero experience and this is so valuable to ma, so thanks you very much for your time.

Comment: All, I have an answer for the post to the controller issue, but the returned Json object is not updating my labels now. I am so confused as to why. I thought that the partial view code should just work in the same way as if it were in the hosting view itself?

Comment: You deleted your last question just as I was posting this - so I will add it here: Yes you can return a success message (and I recommend you do so) but you are not using client side validation because 1. you changed the `name` attribute screwing up everything associated model binding and validation and 2. you do not handle the `.submit()` event

Comment: I have this working now. Thanks very much for your time and hep. It really is appreciated. All the very best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the name of the email field is `EmailAddress` not email.. change your parameter name to `string EmailAddress` or you can change your markup to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", Name="email", id = "email" })
```

trick is the make the name of the field and your parameter name match, not the id.

Comment: Brilliant explanation man, thanks. Very new to this, so that really helped. One last thing, any idea why my Json return value is now failing to show the labels, instead it just shows a blank screen with text?

Comment: This is the answer, a bounty if you can tell me why my labels are failing to render!

Comment: sounds like your form is actually submitting instead of being handled by your javascript function.. do you need the `<form>` at all since you're using ajax to post back the data?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I have taken an online example and have built it up. I really have minimal web/MVC knowledge... You think I should take this out?

Comment: i'll create you a dotnetfiddle real quick

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cWvW7x   it may not make a ton of sense to you but i tried to point out what html should be in your partial.. and what your javascript should look like..  I am also using a Model for the parameter to your `SendInvite` action that has an EmailAddress property and a Product property.  The javascript should reflect these property names in the post

Comment: But why have you not had to use your own solution above? It seems that if you include all the code in the main view there is not problem. It is the use of the partial view that is the crux of the issue...

Comment: Don't change the name attribute! Change the parameter of your method to `string emailAddress` (attempting to override the name attributes generated by the html helpers is the surest way to screw up model binding an have your app faiiL

Comment: @JamieD77 The return Json value is still not updating my labels in the partial view. Are you able to tell me why? Sorry to bother you again with this... I can't bounty this yet, but I will do.

Comment: the partial view is just html..  if the exact same code works if all the code is in the main view then it would work in the partial.. you have to be making a change to the markup in the Partial view for it not to work.  You problem is most likely that you're using a BeginForm where you don't need one.  If you put your code inside of BeginForm you need to assume that you're posting to an ActionResult that will return a View, and not a JsonResult.  DotNetFiddle doesn't allow partial views or I would add one and it would work the same.

Answer (score 2):

Killercam, regarding your form submitting. Did you change it back to `type="button"` and not `type="submit"`? If not, reason is when you click the button, it will submit it and will disregard your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try decorating your action method by HttpPost